# Pass a PHP array of data to Google Maps Javascript API

Tags: php, javascript, arrays, google-maps

I have a PHP array (of arrays) of address date like this:

```
$date[0][lat] = 42.54
$date[0][lng] = -80.54
$date[0][title] = Business Name


$date[1][lat] = 41.54
$date[1][lng] = -81.54
$date[1][title] = Another Name
```

etc.

Is it possible to somehow pass this array of arrays to the google maps api to map as markers?  Everything I seem to find online is either working with XML or working with data that is already a javascript array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you use PHP 5.2 or later, you can pass your array as follow

```
<?php print json_encode($date) ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to encode it as json ans then just simply echo into the JS variable:

```
var myGeolocatedItems = <?= $sJsonEncodedArray; ?>;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 var simple ='<?php echo $sparam1; ?>';
```

you can assign any php variable using the above way